# nuget.exe pack excludes files without a dot

Tags: windows-10, nuget

Running the command `nuget.exe pack <path-to-nuspec> -NoDefaultExcludes -OutputDirectory <path-to-output-dir>` on a Windows 10 machine does not include files without a dot, such as "Dockerfile". I have not been able to find any information on this, apart from information on how to include files starting with a dot.

Is it working as intended or am I missing some option? Seems like a strange limitation, gives that Dockerfile is something one might want to include in a nuget package.

Comment: Proper google query is "nuget pack files without an extension".  Old bug, make sure your nuget.exe version is up to date.

Comment: @HansPassant Was using a version downloaded on 28th of April 2021, but I downloaded the last now, 5.9.1.11 and the problem remain.

Comment: Seems to be an open issue https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5158

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for this. In the .nuspec file, just replace

```
<file src="include/**/*.*"                  target="include"     />
```

with

```
<file src="include/**/*"                target="include"     />
```

It seems that '*' catches the "*.*" files as well.